# Habilitar y deshabilitar elemento con jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

> De la pregunta del SO original [Disable/enable an input with
>   jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1414365/3683321)

Quiero habilitar y deshabilitar elementos de una página HTML (ya sean inputs, divs, botones, etc.).

**¿Cómo puedo resolverlo utilizando jQuery?**

Comment: asociación: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> De la respuesta del SO original [Disable/enable an input with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1414366/3683321)

### jQuery 1.6+

Para cambiar la propiedad `disabled` debes usar la función [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) function.

```
$("input").prop('disabled', true);
$("input").prop('disabled', false);
```

### jQuery 1.5 e inferior

La función `.prop()` no existe, pero [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) funciona de forma similar:

Establecer el atributo disabled:

```
$("input").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Para habilitar de nuevo, el método adecuado es usar [`.removeAttr()`](//api.jquery.com/removeAttr)

```
$("input").removeAttr('disabled');
```

### En cualquier versión de jQuery

Siempre se puede confiar en el objeto actual del DOM y es probablemente un poco más rápido que las otras dos opciones si sólo se trata de un elemento:

```
// assuming an event handler thus 'this'
this.disabled = true;
```

La ventaja de usar los métodos `.prop ()` o `.attr ()` es que puede establecer la propiedad para un montón de elementos seleccionados.

---

**Nota:** En 1.6 hay un método [`.removeProp()`](//api.jquery.com/removeProp) que suena mucho como `removeAttr()`, pero **NO DEBE SER USADO** en propiedades nativas como `'disabled'` Extracto de la documentación:

> Note: Do not use this method to remove native properties such as checked, disabled, or selected. This will remove the property completely and, once removed, cannot be added again to element. Use .prop() to set these properties to false instead.

**Traducción**:

> Nota: No utilice este método para eliminar propiedades nativas, como
>   checked, disabled o selected. Esto eliminará completamente la
>   propiedad y, una vez eliminada, no se podrá agregar de nuevo al
>   elemento. Utilice .prop() para establecer estas propiedades a false en
>   su lugar.

De hecho, dudo que haya muchos usos legítimos para este método, las propiedades booleanas están hechas de tal manera que debes establecerlos a false en lugar de "eliminarlas" como sus equivalentes de "atributo" en 1.5

Comment: Gracias por copiar y pegar la documentación

Comment: @Javi no sé si ese comentario es sarcástico, si lo es ten en cuenta que esta pregunta es una traducción, hay una lista de preguntas de SO en inglés para traducir: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1320/preguntas-con-enlaces-cruzados-identifiquemos-las-ya-existentes-en-este-sitio

Comment: @blonfu como quieras pero está copiada, aún así es lo de menos, lo que me hace gracia es también como este tipo de preguntas / respuesta reciban más de 3 y 4 votos positivos, a este tipo de preguntas me refiero a que en Google escribes esa pregunta y te salen ya millones de respuestas, luego hay preguntas bastante más interesantes y complejas y no se valoran tanto como deberían. (En ningún momento hablo por mí, si no en general).

Comment: @Javi La respuesta original tiene 2910 votos! Son preguntas que son útiles a mucha gente y por eso cosechan gran cantidad de votos. Seguramente se pueda encontrar la respuesta en muchos sitios pero es interesante para SOes que este aquí y en español. También ha habido debate sobre este tipo de preguntas traducidas, no todos están de acuerdo